# VLOOKUP if only a part of the search criteria matches with the values in the table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A              B               C
1     List       Search Criteria     Result
2   2019-01            9            2019-09
3   2019-02
4   2019-03
5   2019-04
6   2019-05
7   2019-06
8   2019-07
9   2019-08
10  2019-09
11  2019-12
12
```

In `Column A` I have a list of all months in 2019. In `Cell B2` I want to search for a month by just enterring in the number of the month. The result should appear in `Cell C2`. Therefore, I tried to go with the following formula in `Cell C2`:

```
C2 =VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$A$13,1,FALSE)
```

---

The issue is now that basically my **search criteria** is not `2019-09`. It is just `9` and therefore the `VLOOKUP` is not able to find it within `Column A`.

So far I came up with the following solutions to solve this issue:

a) Change the **search criteria** to `="2019-"&B2`. 
b) Add a **helper column** next to `Column A` in which I only dsiplay the number of the months

However, I am wondering if there is smarter solution which does the job within the `VLOOKUP` function directly (maybe a combination with the `MID` function)?

Comment: It depends. Is the data in column A actually a date, but formatted to only show year and month, or is it text?

Comment: if it is a text value you can use int(right(A2,2)) in the vlookup

Comment: It is a text value

Comment: why search? if your list only has 12 months from 2019, then it is certain that 9 will return `2019-09` hence you can just use this formula in cell C2 `=YEAR(TODAY())&"-"&TEXT(B2,"00")` for instance. If your list is much bigger than one year then you probably need to confirm whether the total number of months is known or is changing dynamically from time to time?

Comment: @Terry W: The year which in this case is 2019 can change and it is not always YEAR(TODAY()) It can be any year. Therefore, the VLOOKUP should search the Column independent from the year.

Comment: If it's text, then: `=VLOOKUP(TEXT(B2,"\*00"),$A$2:$A$13,1,FALSE)` should work.

Comment: @Rory: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I am only giving you an example. I guess you already know the year component so you do not need to use YEAR function but just cite the exact year instead. Again if your list only has 12 months from 1 to 12 then there is no need to look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments below the question there are two solutions to solve the problem:

**Option A)** 
If the year in the list **does not** change and will be the same you can go with this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(B2,"\*00"),$A$2:$A$13,1,FALSE)
```

**Option B)** 
If the year in the list changes you can go with this formula and edit the first parameter accordingly:

```
=VLOOKUP("2019-"&TEXT(B2,"00"),$A$2:$A$13,1,FALSE)
```

Comment: if cell A2 is 2010-09, the vlookup will return 2010-09 instead of 2019-09.

Comment: I think your missed my point. If you already know the year to search is 2019 (or 2018 or 2017 etc.), and you want to search `9` to return `2019-09`, why don't you just use `="2019-"&TEXT(B2,"00")` to return `2019-09` for instance?

Comment: FWIW; In your current setup all you would need is: `=INDEX(A2:A11,B2)`